# Redux-form reset/remove syncErrors

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

On an input I have added a `required` validate function. When I check the checkbox below I can disable this input. But if the user have already had an action on it (onBlur I think) the value syncErrors in my redux store stay. So when I disabled the input I keep it required.

How can I manage to remove this value from syncErrors.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically remove `required` validate function from input when 'disabled' checkbox  is checked. 
No validators -> no syncErrors.

```
const firstNameFieldValidators = isDisabledValue ? [] : [required];

<Field
    name="firstName"
    type="text"
    component={renderField}
    validate={firstNameFieldValidators}
    disabled={isDisabledValue}
    label="First Name"
/>
```

> [Full example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qp7wl7qz9)